# How to create a list of Characters from list length?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list:

```
list = [4,2,3]
```

I am trying to create them as counters for a list of characters like so i end up with this:

```
list = [[A, A, A, A][B, B][C, C, C]]
```

How would i go about this in Python?

Thank you,

Comment: Down voters, always have an habit to explain why you down voted. Lets be polite and explain. :)

Comment: @LearningNeverStops If you hover over the downvote button, you'll read: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or or not useful". I don't think copypasting this every time you downvote is productive. New users should probably take time to understand what downvoting means...

Comment: @sashkello aah true, I forgot that option over there :).

Answer (score 3):

Contents of play.py

```
import string
def make_lists(a):
    characters = string.uppercase  # Relace this with your custom char set if necessary
    my_list = [[c] * n for n, c in zip(a, characters)]
    return my_list
```

Output:

```
In [11]: a = [4, 2, 3]

In [12]: play.make_lists(a)
Out[12]: [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
in_list = [4, 2, 3]
out_list = [[string.uppercase[i]] * j for i, j in enumerate(in_list)]
print out_list
```

Btw, don't call your variable `list`, it's the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution:

```
s = [4,2,3]
>>> [ [chr(y)]*x for x,y in zip(s, range(ord('A'), ord('A') + len(s))) ]
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through list comprehension:

```
lst = [4,2,3]
chars = ['A', 'B', 'C']
[[chars[j] for _ in range(lst[j])] for j in range(len(lst))]
```

As other answers suggest, if you just need letters in alphabetic order you can use `string` module

```
import string
[[string.uppercase[j] for _ in range(lst[j])] for j in range(len(lst))]
```